# OpenGL - Creating a vbo on a thread in ubuntu?

Tags: c++, multithreading, opengl, thread-safety, x11

I have an app in which I have remote mesh data on a server. Some of these meshes have 400k vertices and thus require threading during the download process. I have no issue when running everything on one thread and all code is working fine except for when I go to upload the downloaded buffers into openGL land in the threaded version. I eventually get a crash when attempting to create the vbo with the opengl calls. The application usually segfaults on  glGenBuffers. Some examples I read when trying to get OpenGL calls thread safe involved specific windows apis and platform specific stuff that is not much of a help in the x11 ubuntu environment.

So I am hoping someone who has done this before can point me to a few calls to make so this may be viable before re-architecting a working piece.

My loading code is very simple and light weight, and the vbo uploading is the typical steps of glGenBuffer, glBind, glBufferData calls:

```
///
/// \brief The LoadMeshThread class
///     Thread to load a mesh (geometry data) from database
///
class LoadMeshThread : public vtrus::core::Thread
{
    CLASSEXTENDS(LoadMeshThread, vtrus::core::Thread)
    ADD_TO_CLASS_MAP
public:
    VTRUS_HOST
    LoadMeshThread( Chunk* chunk, uint32_t mapID, ChunkGrid* chunkVolume ) :
      super(),
      ChunkToLoadMesh(chunk),
      CpuVertices(NULL),
      CpuNormals(NULL),
      VertexCount(0),
      ChunkVolume(chunkVolume)
    {
        printf("Loading [%s]\n", chunk->GridLocation.ToString().str());
        MapID = mapID;

        ChunkToLoadMesh->AddRef();
        ChunkGrid::LiveLoadThreads++;
    }

    ///
    /// \brief ~LoadHashThread
    /// Destroyed after pthread has ended
    virtual ~LoadMeshThread()
    {
        vprintf(vtrus::debug::Threading, "[%d]\n", this->ThreadID);
        ChunkToLoadMesh->Release();
        ChunkGrid::LiveLoadThreads--;
        delete [] CpuVertices;
        delete [] CpuNormals;
    }

    ///
    /// \brief Run
    ///  Called by base class when the pthread is created
    virtual void Run();

    ///
    /// \brief ReadFromDataBase
    ///
    void ReadFromDataBase();

private:
    ChunkGrid* ChunkVolume; //Access to world data
    uint32_t MapID;
    vtrus::slam::Chunk* ChunkToLoadMesh;
    GLfloat* CpuVertices;
    GLfloat* CpuNormals;
    int VertexCount;
};

///
/// \brief LoadMeshThread::ReadFromDataBase
/// Calls into mysql and grabs the blobs containing the data
void LoadMeshThread::ReadFromDataBase()
{
    Eigen::Vector3i chunkR3 = ChunkToLoadMesh->GridLocation.ToEigen();
    uint32_t chunkID = R3ToChunkID( chunkR3 );
    vtrus::database::DataBase* vtrusDB = vtrus::database::DataBase::GetInstance();

    {
        vtrusDB->Driver->threadInit();
        {
            try
            {
                vtrus::core::String connectionString = vtrusDB->GetConnectionString();
                sql::Connection* connection = vtrusDB->Driver->connect(connectionString.str(), "gobble", "gobblegobble" );
                connection->setSchema( "gobble" );

                sql::ResultSet* result = vtrusDB->GetMeshData( connection, chunkID, MapID, 1 );

                if( result != NULL && result->next() )
                {
                    std::istream* verticesBlob = result->getBlob("VertexBuffer");
                    std::istream* normalsBlob = result->getBlob("NormalsBuffer");
                    VertexCount = result->getInt("VertexCount");

                    uint bufferSize = VertexCount*sizeof(vtrus::geometry::Vec3f);
                    CpuVertices = new GLfloat[bufferSize];
                    CpuNormals = new GLfloat[bufferSize];
                    //printf("Loading %d entries \n", entryCount );
                    verticesBlob->read( reinterpret_cast<char*>(&CpuVertices[0]), (std::streamsize)bufferSize );
                    normalsBlob->read( reinterpret_cast<char*>(&CpuNormals[0]), (std::streamsize)bufferSize );

                    delete verticesBlob;
                    delete normalsBlob;
                }

                delete result;
                delete connection;
            }
            catch ( sql::SQLException * exception )
            {
                //do nothing
                printf("WARNING: SqlException on Loading\n");
            }
        }
        vtrusDB->Driver->threadEnd();
    }
}

void LoadMeshThread::Run()
{
    vtrus::core::ScopedTimer timer("**** LoadHashThread::Run ****");

    vprintf(vtrus::debug::Threading, "[%d]\n", this->ThreadID);
    int numAttempts = 0;
    const int maxAttenpts = 10;
    uint countRemaining = 0;
    uint maxCount = 0;

    ReadFromDataBase();

    if( VertexCount > 0 )
    {
        printf("Creating [%d] vertices\n", VertexCount);
        //CRASH here when the mesh constructor calls glGenBuffer          
        vtrus::resources::Mesh* newMesh = new vtrus::resources::Mesh(VertexCount);
        //upload cpu vertices / normals to GPU

        glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, newMesh->GetVertexBuffer()->bo );
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexCount * sizeof(vtrus::geometry::Vec3f), &CpuVertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, newMesh->GetNormalsBuffer()->bo);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexCount * sizeof(vtrus::geometry::Vec3f), &CpuNormals[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );

        ChunkVolume->AddMesh(newMesh, ChunkToLoadMesh);
        newMesh->Release();

        ChunkToLoadMesh->IsLoaded = true;
        ChunkToLoadMesh->IsSaved = true;
        ChunkToLoadMesh->SavedBlockCount = maxCount;
    }

    //Access mutex
    ChunkToLoadMesh->IsLoading = false;
}
```

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from processing the mesh in the worker thread, and passing a data pointer to your GL thread, which would then dispatch it?

Comment: I suppose not other than needing to track the cpu pointers from the main thread after the worker thread dies. I can definitely do that, just wishful thinking on keeping the mesh creation as its own code unit I guess :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before any `glXXX` command can be used, the gl-context must be set as current to the thread that will use those commands.

In X11 world the command to use is `glXMakeContextCurrent` or older but still valid `glXMakeCurrent`. See [glX doc](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glx1.4.pdf). If you are using some library that handles gl-context for you, then search in its documentation.

You can upload the data in a gl-context and render it in another gl-context. For this both contexts must be "shared", something you usually do at their constructors.

But if your graphics card is not capable of *reading while rendering* there won't be a great perfomance-improvement.